# Change value of cell in string so that it is when placement like '%C4%' then 'D4', when placement like '%C5%' then 'D5' etc

Tags: excel-formula

How do I change the value of the cell in the string so that is is when placement like '%C4%' then 'D4', when placement like '%C5%' then 'D5' etc.?

[image]

I have tried find and replace but that is not it

Comment: Please share a sample list of strings, and also demonstrate the expected outcome clearly. Having that said, I think you are after functions such as **SUBSTITUTE** and/or **REPLACE**.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs and suggestions. I apologize since my question was badly framed and will take a more careful approach in the future

Comment: so have you solved your question? you can edit your post to share some sample strings and specify the result that you are after. And maybe share the formula you have tried and tell us where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not sure what you really want, but this may start you off:

```
=IF(A2=B2,C2,"")
```

As you drag down A2 becomes A3 etc

Comment: @ShivaniAgarwal please use the tick or check mark to accept the answer - this enables the system to sort the question properly so it is not reposted later.